# Как правильнее всего получать столбец матрицы?

Tags: c++

Есть объект типа матрица. Сам объект представляет из себя размер матрицы и указатель на указатель на тип `int`. Если я хочу получить строку, то мне достаточно лишь возвращать в перегруженном операторе указатель из массива указателей, тогда я могу изменять элемент этой матрицы и получать значение, прописав что-то типа `matrix[2][3]`. Но что, если я захочу получать не строчку, а столбец? Пробовал создавать дополнительный объект внутри класса матрицы, который хранит указатель на матрицу и номер столбца. А потом для этого нового объекта перегружать оператор, чтоб получать элемент этого столбца через указатель на матрицу. Но я думаю, что есть более изящный способ. От туда и вопрос, как?

Comment: По идее - выделить память, скопировать значения, отдать. Кому доверить освобождение памяти (вызывающей стороне или матрице) - на ваше усмотрение.

Comment: @Kromster а разве я смогу так менять значение элемента матрицы, если изменю элемент столбца? Скорее всего я не до конца понимаю ваше решение.

Comment: Если нужно иметь возможность менять значения в столбце извне, то можно возвращать массив указателей .. Вообще же, тут все уже зависит от сценариев использования - можете и указатель на всю матрицу возвращать, и размерность в шапке хранить, ит итд. *Нету единого "правильного" способа соединять 2 доски.*

Comment: В целом вы правильно думаете. В объекте column достаточно хранить указатель на элемент столбца в нулевой строке матрицы и размер строки матрицы

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan

Comment: @Kromster это тупа, но в задании надо получать доступ к элементу вида matrix[3][4], а если возвращать массив указателей, то это будет уже *matrix[3][4], что в нашем условии не допускается(моей универской задаче)

Comment: @tocic так там ведь только с 23 стандарта такая вещь появится, разве нет?

Comment: @МаксимГерасимов да, но это не мешает посмотреть [дизайн](https://wg21.link/P0009) и [реализацию](https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan) и сделать подобным образом уже сегодня

Comment: @tocic найти бы там еще реализацию))

Answer (score 1):

> указатель на указатель на тип int

Зря, лучше использовать одномерный массив размера N * M.

Возврату строк это не помешает. Если `p` - указатель на первый элемент, а `w` - ширина матрицы, то для `i`-ой строки возвращать указатель `p + w * i`.

А чтобы вернуть столбец, достаточно вернуть вспомогательный объект, хранящий `q` - указатель на первый элемент столбца, и `w` - ширину матрицы. Тогда, если у этого объекта спросить `j`-ый элемент столбца, он сможет вернуть `q[w * j]`.

Comment: В таких маневрах, смущает только то, что не указывается размерность матрицы (в том числе, она может быть и не квадратной).

Comment: @Kromster Для прямоугольных это тоже работает.

Comment: Конечно работает, просто не известно насколько большим может быть `j` чтобы не выйти за границы ;-)

Comment: @Kromster А, вы про то, что хорошо бы проверять выход за границы?

Comment: Ну не то что хорошо бы, а надо бы )) Просто у ТС вопрос слишком неконкретный, но мне кажется, судя по тому что получения столбика - проблема, матрицы явно не 3х3 или 4х4, а много больше. Но это лишь комментарий, не упрек.

Comment: А разве это не тоже самое, что и у меня, за исключением того, что сама матрица по-другому представлена? Я то именно для своего типа матрицы ищу решение)
(Чтоб был двумерный массивчик)

Comment: @МаксимГерасимов Представление матрицы одним длинным куском - лучше, мне кажется. Это позволяет перейти к следующему элементу столбца просто прибавив к указателю ширину матрицы. Плюс, память выделяется за одно обращение к куче, что должно быть быстрее, и строки находятся в памяти подряд, что должно быть хорошо для кеша.

Comment: @МаксимГерасимов Массив указателей новички обычно используют, потому что он с ходу позволяет получить привычный синтаксис с двумя парами квадратных скобок, без перегрузок операторов - но это так себе причина, и `[]` у вас в любом случае перегружен. Вторая причина - возможность иметь строки разной длины, но это вроде не ваш случай.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat понял вас. Но все равно интересно, можно ли еще как-то, без доп объектов. И не используя 23 стандарты и тем более не изучая тамошние реализации

Comment: @МаксимГерасимов А при чем здесь С++23? Я не предлагаю `[]` с несколькими аргументами. И непонятно, чем не угодили дополнительные объекты, их же не нужно хранить постоянно в матрице. Создавать только при вызове `[]`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я про предыдущего комментатора. А по поводу доп объектов... Мне все норм, просто задача интересная и стало интересно для души узнать, как еще можно.

Comment: @МаксимГерасимов А без доп. объектов - это как? Когда вы возвращаете столбец, элементы идут в памяти не подряд, поэтому указатель вернуть нельзя. Остается только объект кастомного класса.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я тоже об этом думал, но мало ли. Подумал, что может метапрограммисты в этом комьюнити могут че-то еще предложить)